# Why is an alpha emitter used in smoke alarms?

Tags: particle-physics

So basically I was wondering the main reasons why alpha particle emitters are used over (beta and gamma) in smoke alarms

Comment: Gammas are waaaay too penetrating and would leave the detector.

Comment: Even multi-MeV alphas will not penetrate the layer of dead skin cells you have. So, as long as you don't inhale the smoke detector there are no bad health effects.

Comment: Actually, the decay of $241_{Am}$ produces  a $3^{1}_{0}n$ and a $\gamma$

Comment: BTW, ionization smoke detectors using alpha emitters have been losing ground to photoelectric smoke detectors because ionization smoke detectors are not as good at detecting smoldering fires. The fact that ionization detectors pose disposal issues when it comes time to replace them hasn't helped them, either.

Comment: @CinaedSimson - no, $^{241}$Am is definitely an alpha emitter. Recheck your table of isotopes.

Comment: @JonCuster: my bad - you're right. I read the tables to quickly. The decay I was looking at had an extremely small branching ratio and a half life on the order of micro-seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smoke detectors are either photoelectric, ionization chamber, or combination. In photoelectric a weak light beam is aimed at a photo receptor. A rapid change in received light intensity indicates smoke. In an ionization chamber a strongly ionizing medium is used to rip electrons off of smoke particles, thus ionizing them. The detector senses the ionized particles and triggers the alarm.

The main reason that alpha particles are used is that they are strongly ionizing, because they are helium nuclei without any orbiting electrons; they will rip electrons off of any particles that they encounter, whereas gamma rays and beta particles will not.

The main isotope used for ionization smoke alarms is [Americium-241](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americium-241) with a half-life of 432.2 years.

Comment: This is clearly a silly question but I'm intrigued.   why would the use of  Californium-241 with a half-life of 4 minutes be unsuitable for use in a smoke detector?

Comment: @Ineedhelp Well, aside from the half-life of 4 minutes (which would render the smoke detector inoperable in quite a short time, much less than a year for sure), Cf-241 doesn't seem to be a particularly abundantly-produced isotope, so it would require some substantial infrastructure to be built before it can be mass-produced.

Comment: Thanks.  any other reasons why alpha particles are used?

Comment: @Ineedhelp, as mentioned previously in remarks, alpha particles don't penetrate deeply, so the plastic that contains the ionization chamber is sufficient to stop alpha particles. I guess one could say that an alpha emitter doesn't require a power source, but I'm not sure how significant that is.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. What is getting ionized? Why does it have anything to do with smoke? Wouldn't air just get ionized all the time?

Comment: @BenCrowell, I thought, "...rip electrons off of particles..." was pretty clear, but I changed it to "...smoke particles..." just to make it clearer, and the OP just asked why alpha emitters are used, not how they work. Why electrons don't get ripped from O2 & N2 or trigger the alarm seems to me to be a separate question.

Comment: Yes, @BillDOe is correct I only asked why they are used.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is incorrect. The alpha particles are used because they are strongly ionising, but not just so that they can ionise the smoke particles. Oxygen and nitrogen molecules in the air are constantly ionised and the electrons and ions are attracted to positive and negative electrodes, which creates a potential difference, and consequently, a current. When smoke enters, it is *not* ionised, which disrupts the current and triggers the alarm.
Another reason alpha particles are used is that they aren't very penetrating and have a very short range, so they won't affect any people in the house.